# How to get the document name of google spreadsheet?

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to open a google spreadsheet using:

```
 import gspread
 sheet = gc.open_by_key(sheetkey)
```

after opening the sheet. I want get the name of document that was opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the spreadsheet is stored as an object variable `title`. You can simply do `sheet.title` to get the title. [Docs](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.title)

The same can be done for worksheets as well.